# Поменять og-image на сайте Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

Подскажите, как быть..
меняю мета теги везде где только можно на своё изображение, но в итоге при копировании ссылки в скайпе или в фейсбук все равно получаю старое. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо, чтоб было только первое..
Пользовался плагином "OG" , прописывал в header.php u functions.php в ручную следующий код:

```js
$first_img = "http://lostandfoundthenovel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/2.png";

function catch_that_image() {  
    global $post, $posts;  
    $first_img = '';  
    ob_start();  
    ob_end_clean();  
    $output = preg_match_all('//i', $post->post_content, $matches);  
    $first_img = $matches [1] [0];  
    if(empty($first_img)){  
            //Определяет картинку по умолчанию 
            $first_img = "http://lostandfoundthenovel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/2.png";
        }  
    return $first_img;  
}  

add_filter('og_image_init', 'my_og_image_init');
function my_og_image_init($images)
{
    if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) {
        $images[] = 'http://lostandfoundthenovel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/2.png';
    }
    return $images;
}
```

```html
<meta property="og:image" 
      content="<?php if (function_exists('catch_that_image')) 
      {echo catch_that_image(); }?>" />
```

Но толку нет.. оно то генерится, в инспекторе показывается, что есть новый мета тег, но отображается все равно старое..
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Сайт](http://lostandfoundthenovel.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае, когда `FB` уже однажды постил ссылку на тот или иной ресурс в сети, он кеширует данное изображение, по понятным причинам. В связи с этим, в итоге вы будете получать картинку из его кеша, а не с сайта.

Чтобы исправить данную ситуацию, вы можете зайти в `Facebook Open Graph Debugger` ([ссылка](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)) и там воспользоваться функцией `Scrape again`. Заодно, слева от нее можно увидеть, сколько времени назад производилось последнее кеширование. Ну и остальные интересные результаты там тоже есть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В скайпе та же ситуация .. как быть тогда ? И лбдям, которые тоже копируют эту ссылку как быть ?

Comment: По поводу Скайпа можно попробовать создать отдельный вопрос, а по поводу ФБ - автоматом он обновляет раз в 24 часа, насколько я помню, если же есть желание обновлять самостоятельно, то ответ есть тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100574/is-there-an-api-to-force-facebook-to-scrape-a-page-again